# Soundcloud API over HTTPS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create custom soundcloud players with Plangular: a directive that use SC API and Angular JS.
I tryed with some basic examples, loading the module with my client ID

```
var player = angular.module('player', ['plangular'])
   .config(function(plangularConfigProvider){
   plangularConfigProvider.clientId = '5dcb5ea7cb935713b230330006d1765e';
});
```

and initialize the `<body ng-app="player">`. This works perfect over HTTP, the songs are loaded correctly; but over HTTPS it doesn't play the song. Anyone knows if maybe Soundcloud API has problems to load over HTTPS?

Here are the two example:

Example Over HTTP: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBZyX/34/)

Example Over HTTPS: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s0fbe5q8/1/)

Comment: It's actually working, I think its jsFiddle which causing the issue. https://jsbin.com/bobemer/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes, I fix for the ones I received a valid answer. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's your fiddle which is broken - its running fine under HTTPS - Resource load: >> [Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sacyubyw/).

You selected the config `"Load Type: onLoad"` in the fiddles JavaScript configuration. Once you set it back to `"Load Type: "No wrap - in <body>"` it works like a charm.

[image]